# Select all columns except certain Data_Type (e.g. image) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to view all columns except columns with Data_Type=image.
For example.
Below is the information schema of my table.

[image]

So technically I want to remove the columns with datatype=image which is the 'permissions' on my table view.
The desired code should somehow looks like this.

```
select * from dbo.Locations where Data_Type isnot image
```

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL.  I might suggest that you set up a view instead with the non-image columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not on SQL Server 2017 or higher yet, then you can do this the old-fashioned way:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT TOP 100 ';
SELECT @sql += STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.name
    FROM
        sys.tables t
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
    WHERE
        s.name = 'dbo'
        AND t.name = 'locations'
        AND ty.name != 'image'
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');
SELECT @sql += ' FROM dbo.locations';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to generate your query based on the information schema. In your case you could do it like this:

```
select cast(N'select ' as nvarchar(max)) +
       STRING_AGG(cast(N'[' + column_name + ']' as nvarchar(max)), ',') within group (order by ordinal_position) +
       cast(' from [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']' as nvarchar(max))
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Locations' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and DATA_TYPE not in ('image')
 group by TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

and then execute the generated query.
Due to the use of STRING_AGG, this will work starting with the SQL server 2017

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want permission column then instead of "star" you can write the column names in the query
ex:
select locationid,parentid,....from dbo.Locations

OR

You can use this approach to get the data from all the columns except one:-

Insert all the data into a temporary table
Then drop the column which you don't want from the temporary table
Fetch the data from the temporary table(This will not contain the data of the removed column)
Drop the temporary table
Something like this:

SELECT * INTO #TemporaryTable FROM YourTableName

ALTER TABLE #TemporaryTable DROP COLUMN Columnwhichyouwanttoremove

SELECT * FROM #TemporaryTable

DROP TABLE #TemporaryTabl